# Can I open same project in multiple visual studio IDE to work simultaneously

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Just I want to know we work on same project opened in multiple VS IDE? or it would encounter some conflict by doing so.

My solution has 80 project with referenced another projects so it takes nearly 20 mins to execute single project. I am using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: You can open the project multiple times, each IDE would be sharing the same files though, so if you made changes to File A in one IDE as well as changes to File A in another IDE and saved both, you may overwrite changes from IDE A with IDE B. Are you using any kind of source control?

Comment: There might be some conflict with obj and bin folder as well those will generate on same location from two projects? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can open the project(s) multiple times, each same project will share the same files however, so if you make changes to File 1 in one IDE and changes to File 1 in another IDE and saved both, you may overwrite changes made the first time. There will be conflict if you build before finishing an already happening build process, note that the same executable is being created and/or modified, it will be worse if you rebuild or clean since these involve delete operations. Lastly, the memory footprint of Visual Studio alone is large enough that if you open enough IDEs at some point, it will be faster and lighter to have one IDE with all your projects. Note that you can also unload the projects you don't need, this will boost the overall IDE performance, and of course, you can always load  the unloaded projects when you need them. Lastly, when unloading, sometimes you need to keep in mind project dependencies on each other, such as when one project build depends on the build of another project.